# Using pointers in C++Amp

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, gpgpu, c++-amp

I've got a following issue:

I have a code which does a very basic operation. I am passing a pointer to a concurrency::array_view because I wanted to store the values earlier to avoid the bottle-neck in the function which uses multithreading. The problem is the following construction won't compile:

```
parallel_for_each((*pixels).extent, [=](concurrency::index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
{
int row=idx[0];
int col=idx[1]; 

    (*pixels)(row, col) = (*pixels)(row, col) * (*taps)(row, col); //this is the problematic place 
});
```

Does anybody know how to solve this case? I **really** need to prepare the data before running the method so it's the only way to do it like this because I cannot afford spending time on copying the data between RAM and accelerator's memory.

//EDIT:

After solving some issues with the header files, I am left with following problem:

```
parallel_for_each((*pixels).extent, [=](concurrency::index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
{
int row=idx[0];
int col=idx[1]; 
});
```

The code above doesn't work (it gives exception). Is there **ANY** way to prepare the data earlier so for example the constructor of the class can handle the copying it just one time? I really need to have a pointer to array_view in my header file and initialize it in the constructor as follows:

in cci_subset.h:

```
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> *pixels, *taps;
```

and in the subset.cpp:

```
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> pixels(4, 4, pixel_array); 
... 
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> taps(4, 4, myTap4Kernel_array);
```

//EDIT 2:

I found out that the parameters for parallel_for_each can be only passed by value. That's why I am still looking for a way to copy the values from CPU to GPU when intializing the class or passing some arguments (i.e. image data) to the class.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: 'pixels': using global or static variables is unsupported in amp restricted code 

I had to use global variables as a work-around because including <amp.h> to my project causes whole series of errors and I cannot solve this issue yet. Just wanted to see if it can work.

Comment: You didn't include amp.h? How would that code ever work then? First thing to do is setup your project correctly. Trying to debug a half broken setup is hard and not very useful.

Comment: I DID include amp.h, just not in the header file but in the cpp file. I managed to check that there are problems with methods called min and max (probably there are macros of the same names in amp.h).

Answer (score 1):

**Your C++ AMP issue**

C++ AMP supports two core data types for referencing data on the GPU

> An array represents data on an accelerator. You can construct it and
> fill it with data in a single step or  construct it and fill it with
> data later. In either case, after some calculations have been
> performed on  it, you will almost certainly copy the results from an
> array back to the CPU so that you can use them in  some other part of
> your application.
>
> You can certainly write useful applications using only arrays,
> but C++ AMP also offers the  array_view, which supports features
> that often make it more convenient than working directly with  arrays.
> An array_view looks like an array to the accelerator, but it saves you
> the trouble of arranging to  copy the data to and from the
> accelerator.
>
> The relationship between an array_view and an array is
> somewhat (but not precisely) like that  between a reference and the
> object it refers to. Like a reference, array views must be initialized
> when  they are created. Also as with a reference, changing the
> array_view changes (eventually) the data it  was created from. However,
> the reverse is not true: changing the data from which the
> array_view was  created might not automatically change the array_view,
> so you should approach such operations with care.

From: [C++ AMP: Accelerated Massive Parallelism](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735664730)

I don't think your use of `pixels` is the problem per-se. You cannot use globally scoped variables within a C++ AMP lambda, period. There is no way around this. The C++ AMP code is executing on a device with a different memory space.

You can however initialize your `array` or `array_view` objects earlier in a separate method or constructor and then pass them to the function that does all the work. The following code does something along these lines. `m_frames` is an array of pointers to (C++ AMP) `array` objects that are declared as pare of the class and then initialized in `ConfigureFrameBuffers`.

Note that it uses STL smart pointers, something I would strongly recommend over raw pointers.

```
class FrameProcessorAmpBase
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<array<float, 2> m_frame;

public:
    FrameProcessorAmpBase()
    {
    }

void ConfigureFrameBuffers(int width, int height)
{
    m_frame = std::make_shared<array<float, 2>>(height, width)); 
}
```

**Your min/max header issue**

This is probably because you are including windef.h, or something that takes a dependency on it. This is a known issue when mixing STL and Windows headers. The way to "fix" it is to define `NOMINMAX` at the top of your file before any other includes and then use the min/max functions declared by STL or AMP (which also defines min/max for use in `restrict(amp)` lambdas).

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

If you are using GDI you'll have issues there too as it requires the Windows MIN/MAX macros.

I wrap GIDPlus.h in a wrapper header that contains the following:

```
#pragma once

#define NOMINMAX
#include <algorithm>
#ifndef max
    #define min std::min
#endif
#ifndef min
    #define max std::max
#endif
#include <gdiplus.h>
#undef max 
#undef min
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As far as I understand, in my case I should use `std::shared_ptr<array_view<float, 2> pixels;` in my header file?

Comment: I think I don't fully understand this lines of code: 


`std::generate(m_frames.begin(), m_frames.end(), [=]()>std::shared_ptr<array<ArgbPackedPixel, 2>> 
{ 
  return std::make_shared<array<ArgbPackedPixel, 2>>(int(m_height),   int(m_width), m_accelerator.default_view); 
});`

Could you provide a more basic example for the case that I presented in a comment above?

Comment: I've simplified the code. It still uses shared_ptr, if you really feel the need you can replace this with '*' and make_shared with new.

Comment: @AdeMiller Why do you use dynamic allocation for the array at all? I just startet to read your book and see it there all over the place. Any reason..? Why not just `array<float, 2> m_frame;`

Comment: I'd have to dig into the code but in Cartoonizer I think it was done because you cannot create an uninitialized array<> so you end up having to declare a pointer as a class data member rather than the object itself.

Comment: Does this, along with my other answers, make sense now?