# C++ Amp GPU Data is'nt free after deleting the Data of pointer array GPU (dynamic allocation)

Tags: c++-amp

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <amp.h>     
  #include <assert.h>            
  #include <iostream>            
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <ppl.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h> 


  using namespace ::Concurrency;
  using std::vector;   


  static array<double, 1> *P_GPU;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  accelerator default_device(accelerator::default_accelerator);
  accelerator_view acc_v = default_device.default_view;

  int   N = 4*4096*4096;
  double *xdata = new double[N];
  memset(xdata,0,N);

  extent<1> e_b(N);
  P_GPU = new array<double, 1>(e_b, acc_v); // dynamic allocation of array
  array<double, 1> bb(e_b, xdata, acc_v);
  array_view<double, 1> dest(*P_GPU);
  dest.discard_data();

  parallel_for_each(dest.extent, [=,&bb](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
  {
    dest[idx]=bb[idx];
  });
  dest.synchronize();
  std::cout << "before delete .." << std::endl;

  std::cin.get();

  delete [] xdata; // the DATA of xdata pointer is deleted ..
  delete P_GPU;  // the DATA GPU of P_GPU is not deleted ???

  std::cout << "Hit any key to exit..." << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

The binary Code was tested by Microsoft Process Explorer v16.04.

I tested a problem of dynamic allocation of array (or array_view) in C++ AMP..
I see The GPU memory was not free after deleting the P_GPU pointer !!

This program was tested on Matlab ... (mexFunction)-> I have the same problem... ..
delete P_GPU;

> I need to make a dynamic allocation (GPU C++AMP) of matrix in matlab.
>   I find the trick but i have complication when I do a deallocation
>   (delete) matrix **in GPU memory** .... 
>   ????
>   deallocate GPU memory ...

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use a pointer to an array here? Remember P_GPU is a pointer to the array<> which is in turn a container for data on the GPU not the actual data. I guess it would help to understand a bit more about your scenario.

Comment: This is sample program, i allocate data gpu in Matlab

Comment: I need to make a dynamic allocation (GPU C++AMP) in matlab

Comment: If by dynamically allocate an array you mean get a pointer to GPU memory that you can somehow pass to/from MEX then I don't believe this is possible, nor is it what your code actually does. P_GPU points to an array<> in CPU memory that in turn contains reference(s) to GPU resources.

Comment: deleting data GPU in array_view or array (not data pointer)? how change size of array (or array_view) after declaration of constructor? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem following: [Using pointers in C++Amp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936445/using-pointers-in-camp)

please use: std::shared_ptr<>

```
class FrameProcessorAmpBase
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<array<float, 2> m_frame;

public:
    FrameProcessorAmpBase()
    {
    }

    void ConfigureFrameBuffers(int width, int height)
    {
        m_frame = std::make_shared<array<float, 2>>(height, width));
    }
```

Comment: Does that mean that the question is a duplicate (already has an answer)?